# Exclude elements in a css selection

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the background for the `<article>` as a specified gradient, but would like to exclude the last row of the second table from this gradient coloring. I have tried the following css with no luck:

CSS

```
article.blogPosts:not(table.secondPost tr:last-child td:last-child) {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red , blue);  
}
```

HTML

```
<article class = "blogPosts">

    <h2>Personal Programming Projects</h2>

    <section class= "blogPost">
        <table class= "firstPost">
          <tr>
            <th title = "20th October 2015">Blog post 2 - 20th October 2015 - <time datetime="2015-10-20 10:00">10:00</time>am</th>
            <th><input type="checkbox"> <label>Read</label></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>Student Reporting System - Full Stack Developer</h3>
                <ul>
                  <li> Developed a student monitoring system to enable teachers to provide on-going reports on each student.</li>
                </ul>
            </td>       
          </tr>
        </table>
    </section>

    <section class= "blogPost">
        <table class="secondPost">
          <tr>
            <th title = "15th November 2015">Blog post 1 - 15th November 2015 - <time datetime="2015-10-20 10:00">10:00</time>am</th>
            <th><input type="checkbox"> <label>Read</label> </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>Software Engineering Group Project - Lead Programmer</h3>
                <ul>
                  <li>Developed a fast food ordering system for our chosen business - Krusty's Pizza.</li>
                </ul>
            </td>       
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
            </td>   
          </tr>
        </table>
    </section>

</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
article.blogPosts {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red , blue);  
} 
article.blogPosts .secondPost tr:last-child  {
     background: #fff;  
}
```

Please try this style. Hope this will help you.

Comment: This is bad practice. You have simply overwritten the previous color. It's far better to exclude the style in the first place.

Comment: @SamG What? Isn't this the whole point of "cascading" stylesheets...? Every rule we write is overriding the agent styles.

Answer (score 0):

The selector `article.blogPosts` styles the entire article element. Excluding individual child elements with `:not()` will not work, because they are not the elements with the gradient. The parent is.
Explicitly color the row you want to exclude from the gradient by selecting it with an id.

```css
article.blogPosts {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
}
#lastRow {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<article class="blogPosts">

  <h2>Personal Programming Projects</h2>

  <section class="blogPost">
    <table class="firstPost">
      <tr>
        <th title="20th October 2015">Blog post 2 - 20th October 2015 -
          <time datetime="2015-10-20 10:00">10:00</time>am</th>
        <th>
          <input type="checkbox">
          <label>Read</label>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h3>Student Reporting System - Full Stack Developer</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Developed a student monitoring system to enable teachers to provide on-going reports on each student.</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </section>

  <section class="blogPost">
    <table class="secondPost">
      <tr>
        <th title="15th November 2015">Blog post 1 - 15th November 2015 -
          <time datetime="2015-10-20 10:00">10:00</time>am</th>
        <th>
          <input type="checkbox">
          <label>Read</label>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="lastRow">
        <td>
          <h3>Software Engineering Group Project - Lead Programmer</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Developed a fast food ordering system for our chosen business - Krusty's Pizza.</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </section>

</article>
```

Comment: I'd much rather use a not: selector. Otherwise I'm just coloring over an element that's already colored.

Comment: Excluding individual `<tr>` elements with `:not()` will not work, because they are not the elements with the gradient. The `article.blogPosts` is.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cancel parents' `background-color`.

Try this

```css
h2,
.firstPost tr,
.secondPost tr:not(:last-child) {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red , blue);
}




.blogPosts {
  background-color: green;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<article class="blogPosts">

  <h2>Personal Programming Projects</h2>

  <section class="blogPost">
    <table class="firstPost">
      <tr>
        <th title="20th October 2015">Blog post 2 - 20th October 2015 -
          <time datetime="2015-10-20 10:00">10:00</time>am</th>
        <th>
          <input type="checkbox">
          <label>Read</label>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <h3>Student Reporting System - Full Stack Developer</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Developed a student monitoring system to enable teachers to provide on-going reports on each student.</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </section>

  <section class="blogPost">
    <table class="secondPost">
      <tr>
        <th title="15th November 2015">Blog post 1 - 15th November 2015 -
          <time datetime="2015-10-20 10:00">10:00</time>am</th>
        <th>
          <input type="checkbox">
          <label>Read</label>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="lastRow">
        <td colspan="2">
          <h3>Software Engineering Group Project - Lead Programmer</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Developed a fast food ordering system for our chosen business - Krusty's Pizza.</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          excluded
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </section>

</article>
```

Anyway, did you omit some `td` elements or `colspan` attributes on purpose?